# How to execute command in background in unix shell?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, unix, operating-system

> Execute the command and return immediately, not blocking until the command finishes.
>   **Concepts:** Background execution, signals, signal handlers, processes, asynchronous execution 
>   **System calls:** sigset()

How?

Comment: Just call it and put an ampersand operator `mystuff &`

Comment: @user1767754 but if the command produce any output it will be difficult to use any other command

Comment: If you need the output, you can direct it to a different buffer a shell window or a file.

Comment: Check this question and answers: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137759/why-use-nohup-rather-than-exec

Comment: Nah. The answers are all command line wizardry. For C++ you likely want either `fork` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) or `exec` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)

Comment: By the way, `sigset` and friends have been obsolete for about a decade. [Use `sigaction` and friends instead](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) and check the best-before date on your reading material.

Answer (score 1):

You can direct the outputs to a separate buffer, a file if you don't want to spam your current terminal.

```
yourapp >> ~/tempOutput.txt &
```

If you want output it to "nowhere" you can redirect to null

```
yourapp >> /dev/null &
```

Answer (score 0):

**To run the command  :**
`sudo nohup {your command} &`

**To check the running command process id using nohup**
`ps -ef | grep nohup`

**and to kill the command if needed**

`kill {process id}`

Comment: `sudo` is not necessary (at least there is nothing about root privileges in the question)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a command (or shell script) as a background job by appending an ampersand to the command as shown below.

```
$ ./my-script.sh &
```

You can execute a command (or shell script) in the background using &, But the problem with this, if you logout from the session, the command will get killed. To avoid that, you should use nohup as shown below.

example

```
$nohup ./my-shell-script.sh &
```

or

```
$nohup ps -aux &
```

After you execute a command in the background using nohup, the command will get executed even after you logout. But, you cannot connect to the same session again to see exactly what is happening on the screen. To do that, you should use [screen command](https://www.tecmint.com/screen-command-examples-to-manage-linux-terminals/).

Apart from this, I recommend to use tmux, you can create a session and reattach a session any time.

```
$tmux new -s mysessionname
```

More info about [tmux](https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/2961058)